# Get word at point

Tags: words

It's a simple thing. My cursor is over a word and I want to get the word so that I can do something with it. I see a few different ways to do this but want to avoid reinvention and use a standard method.

Comment: The question is unclear. Do something with it where? In a program (code)? Interactively? Both? What kind of something?

Comment: "Read" in Emacs and Emacs Lisp generally means read interactively or read (load) Lisp code. I've edited the question to say "get" the word instead of "read" it.

Comment: What does "get the word" mean? Do you want a Lisp expression whose value is a string contianing the word? Do you want to mark the word? Do you want to put the word in the kill ring?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You can use the function `thing-at-point` and tell it to return the `word` at point and not return any text properties (unless you need them). Example buffer contents (| is the cursor):

> Hello wor|ld

Calling `(thing-at-point 'word 'no-properties)` returns "world".

Answer (score 6):

```
(current-word &optional STRICT REALLY-WORD)
```

> Return the word at or near point, as a string.
>   The return value includes no text properties.

Comment: For my case with subword-mode enabled `(current-word)` handles camelCaseWords properly contrary to `(thing-at-point)`.